# htpasswd is being cached by the network

Tags: linux, networking, devops, system-administration

I am experiencing a bizarre issue with an htpasswd auth being cached somewhere between the webserver and the browser. It still happens with the webserver shutdown and requesting from the command line so appears it has to be some sort of network caching.

The problem is the auth continues to pop up even when the correct credentials are entered. It does work when the network is changed or a VPN is used

The auth is being powered by apache on a AWS linux server.

I have tried disabling the auth (fixes it on other networks)but not on any that previously requested it.

I resorted to turning the webserver off, it still prompts for auth! I have double checked the dns resolves to the correct server, it does.

I have tried circumventing the browser by using cli and the same happens on those specific networks.

I have tried hard resetting the router and also logging in and resetting anything I can find.

As I say, it is affecting more than one user / location.

There is no error but I can only imagine some form of cache at a network or ISP level.

I have also tried waiting to see if any cache expires but after 72 hours it still persists.

I am at a loss and have never seen anything like this

Comment: Are the users on those networks using a proxy? Some will be configured to cache content to save money. Is the traffic over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Thank you for the response: Are the users on those networks using a proxy? No, just a regular internet connection. HTTP or HTTPS: all HTTP

Comment: Can you try switching the traffic to HTTPS? I have a feeling that won't be cached over HTTPS unless that company man-in-the-middles all traffic.